Is variance proportional to the maximum distance between samples of a distribution?
I have two sets of data: one is set1=[2,2,2,4.5] and set2=[2,1.5,2,4.5,2.5]. If I plot their distributions, set1 is:

set2 is:

I would say that set2 is a wider distribution and so I would expect a higher variance. However, this is not. In fact if I calculate, in Matlab, var(set1)=1.5625 and var(set2)=1.3750.
Why is it so ?
I understood that the variance is a measure of the width of distribution, so I expected that set2 had a larger variance since you have a wider range of variability for x values.
EDIT I
Indeed, if we calculate the difference between maximum and minimum value of sample X for set2: Xmax-Xmin=4.5-1.5=3; Difference between maximum and minimum value of sample X for set1:Xmax-Xmin=4.5-2=2.5.
I would say that var is proportional to the maximum distance between points...
EDIT II
I calculated the variance as indicated in Variance & Standard Deviation (that is the definition of variance):
set1:
mean(set1)=2.6250
(2.625-2)^2+(2.625-2)^2+(2.625-2)^2+(2.625-4.5)^2=4.68
4.68/4=1.7
set2:
mean(set2)=2.5
(2.5-2)^2+(2.5-1.5)^2+(2.5-2)^2+(2.5-4.5)^2+(2.5-4.5)^2=9.5
9.5/5=1.9
Indeed, var set2 > var set1.

Variance basically means the spread of data around the mean in a distribution. A higher variance indicates that the data points are more spread out, which results in a wider spread in the distribution graph. Depending on the type of distribution, the variance may vary. In statistical terms, variance is the square of the standard deviation. Standard deviation measures how far each data point deviates from the mean, so variance reflects the overall spread of data from the mean. This relationship is why variance is often described as the degree to which the data points are dispersed.
Now as per your question about set 1 and 2 set two doesn't have a wider distribution (spread, variance)  because there is a point(2.5) in between 2 and 4.5, however in set 1 the distribution (spread, variance)) is wider or higher because the gap between two points i.e 2 and 4.5 is wider.

I don't understand... in set2 the maximum gap between points is higher with respect to set1 (read edit part of the question).
